# How to get a HWND handle out of a System.Windows.Forms.Form

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-c++, handle

Given the form

```
System.Windows.Forms::Form Form1;
```

and the window handle

```
HWND hWnd;
```

How can I set hWnd to the Handle property of Form1 that does truly exist as a public property that "Gets the window handle that the control is bound to. (Inherited from Control.)" according to the [Microsoft documentation of System.Windows.Forms::Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.aspx)? In the constructor of my Form Form1, I've tried

```
hWnd = this.Handle;
```

but the compiler complains:

error C2228: left of '.Handle' must have class/struct/union type is 'MyNamespace::Form1 ^const ' did you intend to use '->' instead?

So I try

```
hWnd = this->Handle;
```

and just

```
hWnd = Handle; // Since I'm in the Form
```

and then the compiler says:

error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'System::IntPtr' to 'HWND' No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called

Comment: What namespace are you using in yout .net program to declare `HWND hWnd;?`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found a solution, and don't care if it's a kludge.

```
hWnd = static_cast<HWND>(Handle.ToPointer());
```

Works.

Answer (score -1):

If anyone else lands here looking to get CWnd as a final result, the next step is:

```
CWnd* pWnd = CWnd::FromHandle(hWnd);
```