# Covnersion from System::IntPtr to HWND

Tags: c++, handle, hwnd, dwm

I have the following C++ code:

```
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
hr = DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(this->Handle, &margins);
```

But, when I try to compile I get the following error:

```
error C2664: 'DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'System::IntPtr' to 'HWND'
```

Is there any other method to get the `HWND` of my form?

Comment: [A possible duplicate here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621437/how-to-get-a-hwnd-handle-out-of-a-system-windows-forms-form)

Comment: The conversion works, but the `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea` still does not work...